# How to use ADT to package an AIR application?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air, adt, package-managers

I just downloaded the AIR SDK, I just don't know how to proceed. Some sites on the internet tells me to execute the

adt -package SIGNING_OPTIONS air_file app_xml [file_or_dir | -C dir file_or_dir | -e file dir ...] ...

command line, but I just don't know how to do it.

The application is already developed and ready to use, but I can't package it.
(I'm using Flash CS5 and it's packager can't be used because it can't publish "Extended Desktop" apps)

Comment: Open a command prompt, go to the flex sdk/bin folder, and type 'adt'.  Then follow the directions to use it.

Answer (score 4):

Just had the same problem. Specifically when trying to compile an "Extended Desktop" app on Mac. The trick was to add "-target native" and change your output to myApp.dmg

So based on TheDarkIn1978 answer the code would look like.

[dropped ADT file path] –package -storetype pkcs12 -keystore [dropped cert.p12 file path] **-target native** myApp.**dmg** [dropped myApp-app.xml file path] [dropped myApp.swf file path] [dropped myIcon.png file path]
[dropped ADT file path] –package -storetype pkcs12 -keystore [dropped cert.p12 file path] -target native myApp.dmg [dropped myApp-app.xml file path] [dropped myApp.swf file path] [dropped myIcon.png file path]

For reference the error I was receiving before was "error 306: Descriptor must support one of the following profiles: desktop, mobileDevice, extendedMobileDevice, tv"

Also if you get an "error 302: Root content myApp.swf is missing from package" it's because you haven't dropped the path in to your swf, or your not running the command from within in your application folder (weird).

Hope this helps.

Comment: regarding the 302: file path has to be given into myApp-app.xml (using forward slashes) relative to the current directly of the command line you are calling ADT from.

Answer (score 1):

this is the current site for [ADT commands](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d128fc240122-8000.html).  follow the link to the subsection on [ADT package commands](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d128cdca935b-8000.html).

if you are packaging for AIR 2.7, you will need to change the *myApp-app.xml* file to reflect the SDK version:

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.7">
...
```

packaging AIR apps is super easy - don't let the command line frighten you.

if you're on a Mac you can drag and drop files into Terminal instead of having to write out their complete path.  start by dropping onto the command line ***AIR SDK > bin > adt***, followed by:

> –package -storetype pkcs12 -keystore

now on the same line, drag in your cert.p12 file, followed by what you want to name your air package, IE "myApp.air", followed by your application discriptor .xml file, your .swf file and any other files related to the package (such as your application icon).  make sure there is a space between each command line argument.

the complete command will look something like this:

> [*dropped ADT file path*] –package
>   -storetype pkcs12 -keystore [*dropped cert.p12 file path*] myApp.air [*dropped
>   myApp-app.xml file path*] [*dropped
>   myApp.swf file path*] [*dropped
>   myIcon.png file path*]

then hit return, enter the password for your cert.p12 file, and ADT will package your AIR application according to the current director of Terminal, or you can also supply a path for your myApp.air argument and it will be written there, IE:  `/Users/me/Desktop/myApp.air`

Comment: I am on Win 7 and I still couldn't do it. The cmd tells me that couldn't access the air file specified. I worked on a workaround already, although.

Comment: My solution was to create .txt files on a folder from AIR and make the other application access them for instructions on how to behave.